# DynamicData - Dynamic Linq Classes

Tags: asp.net, linq, asp.net-dynamic-data

Anybody know if it's possible to;

1. Dynamically create LINQ classes for tables/columns that change regularly?
2. If that creation can be used in DynamicData.

A web app we are developing creates tables and columns in SQL. We want to edit these tables in DynamicData.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used sqlmetal.exe from the SDK, it's a winner.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what type of Database you are running, but you could always have a linq statement that queries the systems schema table and have it return the tables and columns.  Then could use what you return and then use another linq query to break out the information from each table.